# My blogspot domain to a custom domain is not redirecting properly

Tags: blogger

My Blogspot domain http://www.jimankandeka.blogspot.com was redirected to http://www.withjim.com almost a year ago. Though the site works fine half the time, other half it shows an error which I have mentioned below.

Error -

> The page isn't redirecting properly 
>   Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete. 
>   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or
>   refusing to accept cookies.

What can be the problem? Please help.

I am having the same problem with another domain neblog.in which is redirected from india-north-east.blogspot.com.

Comment: Seems more like a problem with the withjim.com domain itself and not with Blogger. I see an A record pointing to "202.71.129.225", is it on purpose? I suggest removing that entry and see if the problem still persists.

Comment: @Hydra - This is what I am getting after removing 202.71.129.225 - www.withjim.com

Comment: Seems like a DNS cache to me. Surely this question better fits into Webmasters SE?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a Firefox issue. I faced something similar when logging into Google Docs using Firefox. When I tried using Chrome it worked fine.

I think the reason for this behaviour is that Google uses a lot of redirects at its end, and there might be one specific for Firefox which is getting into an infinite loop. Or it could be that Firefox is not able to process some of the redirects and hence throws up an error.